# Kendo Grid Date Formatting

Tags: .net, kendo-grid

have two columns in database

[image: Databse Table]

I want to format 'CreatedDate' according to the 'DateFormat' column in a kendo grid. I can use template: "#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(CreatedDate), DateFormat) || '' #", but it wont display correct date format in the date time picker of column filter.

so i'm looking something like this
//format: "{ 0:#= DateFormat #}",

code sample ---------------------------------------------------
columns: [
{
                            field: "CreatedDate",
                            width: "10%",
                            title: "{{ 'CreatedDate' }}",
                            hidden: true,
                            //format: "{ 0:#= DateFormat #}",
}

---

Answer (score 0):

You should specify datatype in model. E.g.

```
dataSource: {
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/tasks",
            dataType: "jsonp"
        },
    },
    schema: {
        model: {
            fields: {
                CreatedDate: { type: "date" }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then on columns,

```
columns:[
    ...
    { title: "CreatedDate", template:"#=kendo.toString(CreatedDate,DateFormat)#"},
    ...
]
```

Comment: this does not change the format of date time picker of filter box

Answer (score 0):

this does not change the format of date time picker of filter box
[image: this does not change the format of date time picker of filter box]